# parse a file for a line with specific text, then logic to determine next steps

Tags: python

I am trying to scan a textfile for a specific keyword. When this keyword is found there's a numeric value on the line that I need to compare to see if it's less than a set value. If it is, the following lines in the file need to be printed/saved until the next keyword is reached.
I hope this makes sense.

Example of the textfile:

```
"saleAmount","500",
text text text
etc etc etc
text text text
"saleAmount","1200",
text text text
etc etc etc
text text text
```

My python file is as follows:

```
import re
info = open("results.txt", "r")
for line in info:
    if re.match("(.*)saleAmount(.*)", line):
        for s in line:
            result=re.findall('\d+', s)
            if (result < 1000)
                print (result)
```

In this case the line with the amount of 500 should be compared to 1000 and printed, as should the following 2 lines.
The line with the amount of 1200 and it's following lines will be ignored.

I can get this to print out the values in a weird one digit a line result but when I add in the comparison I can't get that.

I'm sure this is simple but I'm new to python.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
import re

ls=[]

with open('results.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "saleAmount" in line:
            ls.append(line.strip('\n'))

for num in range(len(ls)):
    for amnt in re.findall('\d+',ls[num]):
        if int(amnt) < 1000:
            print(amnt)
```

What I did is added the file that contain `saleAmount` to a list `ls`, then extracted the numbers and from that list and compared to see if they are less than 1000.

In your case, `result` is obtaining the values whether it contains a number (splits up that number into single digit) or if it contains a string (becomes empty list).

In your original code, try `print(result)` right after you define it without the `if` statement and what's below it. Then you'll get a clearer understanding as to why you can't compare it to 1000

Edit: Include "saleAmount" and following lines

```
import re

ls=[]

with open('data.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        ls.append(line)

for w in ls:
    if "saleAmount" in w and int(re.findall('\d+',w)[0]) < 1000:
        print(w)
        for i in range(1,4):
            print(ls[ls.index(w)+i])
```

Comment: Thanks @Leb . That's almost it. The script does find the amounts lower than 1000. but it doesn't print out the following lines until it meets saleAmount again. It appears to print out the saleAmount multiple times.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you at first. So let me get this straight, if the amount is below 1000, you want that line printed (including the word "saleAmount") and all the following lines? As far those lines are there only 3 lines? Or do they vary?

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear @Leb. I didn't want to overwhelm with info. But yes, if the amount is less than 1000 that entire line and all following lines until the words saleAmount are encountered again should be printed. Then that new 'saleAmount' line is examined as before. The amount of lines will vary

Comment: Perfect ! thank you @Leb. Nice piece of code to study and adapt.